# Telnet to localhost 3306 looses connection to host after few seconds

Tags: networking, mysql, database

When I try to telnet into my localhost port 3306 which belongs to mysql, it shows me the hello packet, then looses connection after a few seconds. My skip networking is set to OFF, I have started and restarted the server several time, uses netstat -na to check if the port is actually listening, and i get 0.0.0.0:3306 Listening.

What exactly could be the problem ?

Comment: Anything useful in the mysql logs?

Comment: would check the logs to see

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on multiple servers and this seems to be normal behavior.

I also believe that telnet is used for debugging and not a mysql client. Just install mysql(client) to make a stable connection and use telnet just to check if the server responds to your request on a certain port.

Comment: I also created the any host (%) and any User (Any) Access, and tried to connect to the database remotely. The connection times out. The firewall settings for both the server and client were all off. Also I tried to telnet into the port from the client side, but it could not connect. @metalmini What can I do to be able to connect to my mysql server remotely.

Comment: Telnet is not intended for debugging - it is often used for this though.

Comment: @Nazario_Jnr did you do a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`? @symcbean Telnet is used to create a connection on its own portnumber to provide a bidirectional interactive text-oriented communication facility using a virtual terminal connection. Not to administrate a database

Comment: Yh, I know. I wasnt doing it to administrate a database. I was just trying to use it to test if the port is actually active. But never mind. I have found what the issue was. Some third party softwares on my computer were implementing some firewall filters.